# How to suppress newline using ECHO?

Tags: vi

ECHO commmand in the script:

`echo "numerical1, numerical2, numerical3, numerical4,numerical5,numerical6, 
numerical7,

numerical8"`

When run the command, and output copied to excel sheet in cell, the numerical7 appears in below cell and numerical8 further below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just copy the putty output and paste it in excel:

Copy what you want from Putty

Then double-click (2 left click) on the cell you want to paste in : this will open this cell for editing. In this state you then paste : it will paste "everything" (if not too long) into that 1 cell (even if there is mutiple lines.

Side note: creating multi-lines cells "by hand" is done by typing in the cell and pressing `[alt]+[return]` (instead of just [return]) to insert another newline inside the same cell.

Comment: it got fixed by running printf '%s/n' instead of echo.